# IMG Tag Remove Border

Tags: html

http://www.flirtwithme.co/main.php#upgrade

On this page there is a blue box image that has a grey border around it.
I've been trying to remove the border without luck:

eg:

```
border: none;
outline: none;
```

the image is part of a sprite and there is no border around the image.
Any ideas?

*** the image is the one on the right - blue box with a tick in it. (second one on the top in the sprite.

Comment: Which of the thousand images are you talking about?

Comment: *** the image is the one on the right - blue box with a tick in it. (second one on the top in the sprite.

Comment: yes I've tried border:0; as well... no luck... very strange.... it normally works...

Comment: the img tag is inside a <li>... no sure if this changes things in anyway

Answer (score 20, accepted):

your image has no src attribute add a transparent.gif to the source and the border will disappear.

Example:

```
<img class="benefitImg" id="iconPersonalizeProfile" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ce/Transparent.gif">
```

**UPDATE:**

Example for sprited background images on list elements. (In this case you have to rearrange the sprite into a vertical sprite)

http://jsbin.com/ebovod/edit#html,live

Comment: oh ok... I was trying to set the src from CSS background... interesting... is there a way to do it without another img...?

Comment: To expand upon, a slightly better way is rather than have an image tag at all simply place the background image on the LI and add some padding left to ensure the text does not overlap - this will allow you to lose the IMG tag. Burntime is correct the grey border is appearing because you have an image tag with no source so it is displaying an error.

Comment: agree with Chris, put the background to the LI and set some padding.

Comment: In which case go back to your original code and change your IMG tag to a SPAN tag and apply the background image to that.

Comment: You would need to layout the sprite in a different way but having the background on the li is the preferred method. I have provided an example to fix your current method.

Answer (score 8):

There's no point using an `<img`> tag if you're going to use CSS background for the image. In an `<img>` tag the `src` attribute is used to specify the foreground image, and it is a mandatory attribute for this tag. Leaving it out will have unexpected results, such as the border effect you're seeing, but this may vary from browser to browser.

If you want to use CSS `background-image`, just use a different HTML tag (eg `<div>`).

If you want to use an `<img>` tag then you need to use the `src` attribute, and not define it in CSS.

The point here is semantics. An image in an `<img>` tag is assumed to be part of the content of the page, hence the image is specified in the HTML code, whereas by defining an image in CSS, you are saying that it is part of the design, and not content.

You should use the method which matches the purpose of your image in the site.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue just now with the white border around my `img` tag. To resolve this I changed from `<img />` to `<object></object>`. This allowed me to control the `content` style or `background-image` style without leaving the ugly white border. (Have to add below CSS)

```
object {
    border: none;
}
```

I know that this has been answered, however I hope it may come of use to someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I simply did

```
<img src="img/my-image.jpg" style="border:none;" />
```

Answer (score -1):

You have set a background image on an `<img>` tag. This is very bad practice.

My suggestion is to change your markup to the following:
(Note the `<span>` instead of the `<img>` tag)

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <span class="benefitImg" id="iconPersonalizeProfile"><span>
        Personalize your Profile using Custom Themes
    </li>
</ul>
```

And then apply these styles:

```
#iconPersonalizeProfile {
    background: url("http://www.staticimages.co/seemeagain/upgrade-sprite.png") -35px -3px;
    display:block;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    float: left;
}
```

That should solve your problem.

Comment: using a empty span is not really better semantically. Forcing inline elements to behave like block elements is also not the best way.

Comment: Agreed, however this solves the OP's problem. The best solution is above - a background image on the `<li>`. As for forcing inline elements to be block, what about HTML5 `header` and other elements that are not block by default?